# Подзапрос с count

Tags: mysql

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Есть две таблицы. Нужно посчитать сколько значений каждому `category_id` соответствует из таблицы `question`.

```
SELECT category_id, (
    SELECT COUNT(question.id) FROM question JOIN survey_category ON question.category_id = survey_category.category_id GROUP BY survey_category.category_id
    ) as total
    FROM survey_category
    WHERE survey_id = 1
```

в итоге нужно получить на выходе массив вида

```
[1] => [
['category_id' => 12, 'total' = 123]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так часто бывает досидишься за кодом до ручки и элементарные вещи в ступор вгоняют. И стоит лишь сформулировать вопрос - ответ приходит сам собой. :)

```html
SELECT category_id, ( SELECT COUNT(question.id) FROM question WHERE question.category_id = survey_category.category_id ) as total FROM survey_category WHERE survey_id = 1
```

Вопрос закрыт. Спасибо всем. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.category_id, count(1) FROM survey_category c
    LEFT JOIN question q ON  c.category_id=q.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_id
WHERE survey_id = 1
```